# Using .htaccess in Codeigniter(mod_rewrite)

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am trying to learn about mod_rewrite.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /indexl.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /indexl.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ indexl.php?/$1 [L]

    </IfModule>
```

This is the content of my .htacces file in CI. I use this file because supossedly it works on some other application. However this does not work if I change the name of the index.php I get the directory structure in the browser.  So I am wondering if it is working even when the name of the file is index.php, or does it automaticly use index.php. Shouldnt this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ indexl.php?/$1 [L]
```

redirect every request to indexl.php???

Comment: "redirect every request to indexl.php???". Yes! But if not a file or directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RewriteRule snippet redirects depending the URL path given. If you specify an empty one with `http://example.com/`, then the `-f` and `-d` checks won't fail. Thus there will be no rewriting to said `indexl.php` script.

And in absence of any `index.*` file (wether .php or .html) Apaches auto index (directory list) will take over.

You can however use:

```
DirectoryIndex indexl.php
```

So with an empty path your index script will still run.

Comment: Thanks for the answer so if understand correctly the conditions before the last rule check if the what the user is trying to access is not a valid file and are fulfiled if the request is indeed not a valid file?

Comment: Exactly. With the empty path the REQUEST_FILENAME will refer to the DOCUMENT_ROOT, which is present; so the final RewriteRule won't be applied.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you look at [the Code Igniter User Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html). You'll see:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Which is a pretty typical rewrite used by Code Igniter users. So, if you add put this in a .htaccess file in the root of your app directory, you can have urls like:

```
example.com/my/page
```

rather than

```
example.com/index.php/my/page
```